# Programatically change pattern to <buttons (click)> with Ionic 3.6

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

For and Ionic 3.6 Project:
I have a simple Pipe that gets the tags of any posts from a service in json and turns them to clickeable buttons before rendering the feed. The idea is to turn any #query and turn them into something like  or similar. Pretty common thing to do for any social media like app.
I use the pipe along with the [innerHtml] property to check for any unsafe html code and the text is actually being rendered. The problem is that ionic renders them unusable, the click is not being interpreted as an action but rather as a part of the DOM.

[image]

Searching on the internet I found some guy with the same problem, back in 2016:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11349

Angular's team answer was to use a component from inside the pipe because angular renders components, not plain html.

So I created my tag component and use it from inside the pipe to replace all the #thing's with .
Surprise, the tag-component tag is being rendered, not the component itself

Maybe I'm completely misunderstanding the whole Angular/Ionic way html is being rendered, but I had searched a lot trying to solve this issue that was a no-brainer for my when I was developing on AngularJS. 
Can someone shed me some light on this issue?

EDIT:

The pipe: Lets assume, just for the sake of simplicity, that I get a text from a service with some random #things, and I want to make that #things clickable and call a function to trigger the search with the 'thing' part :

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform,Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    @Pipe({ name: 'mentionAndTag' })

    export class MentionsPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

        transform(value){   
            var regexpTag = /(\#[^\s]+)/gi;

            if (value){
            var changed = function(match){
                       return '<a [click]="searchTag('+match+')">'+ match +'</a>';
                };

            value = value.replace(regexpTag, changed);
            }                                   
            return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(text);
        }   
    }

The code I use to print the text

 <!-- text content of a post -->
        <p 
*ngIf="post.attachments[0] || post.resources[0]" [innerHtml]="post.content | mentionAndTag">
          </p>
```

I even tested with a component (call it 'tag-cmp') so instead of

```
 return '<a [click]="searchTag('+match+')">'+ match +'</a>';
```

I use

```
 return '<tag-cmp [searchText]="+match+'"></tag-cmp>';
```

And use the component template to render the html for my. Both cases the html tag is rendered without the action being actually recognized. I figure that the html is not being rendered properly or maybe it is printed post render, but this is the kind of things you can just do printing the plain html with AngularJS. Why it is so complicated on Angluar? Beats me.
Also, this is a pretty common thing to do on pretty much ANY social app, why is not this particular case being covered on some stackoverflow question or article is beyond me.

Comment: you need to add the relevant code in question..

Comment: @SurajRao Just added code samples.